# Close keyboard when view is pressed - Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function that populates a few fields into the `self.view.window` view.  Now if I run:

```
/* HIDE KEYBOARD WHEN CLICKED AWAY */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //so that action such as clear text field button can be pressed
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

within my `viewDidLoad` it works great.  But lets say I click a `cell -> calls function -> displays using:` `[self.view.window addSubview:self.DatePicker];`

My`gestureRecognizer` will not longer work.  I assume that is because of sending it to the `window`.  My question is, how can I get that to work?

UPDATE:

The reason I am adding to the `window` is because I need to give it a `fixed` like property and that did the trick for me.  For instance in `CSS` you are able to do `position:fixed;`

Comment: Why are you adding subviews to the window and not the view itself? The window should usually only contain your outer view and everything else should be nested inside it.

Comment: Is your view a UIScrollview or similar? If so try this: Take a regular view (#1) and add your scroll view as a subview(#2). Then add your date picker (#3) as a subview to #1 aswell. Apply the gesture Recognizer to view #1.

Comment: @timbodeit what is happening is I have a tableview that populates data.  If a specific cell is clicked I populate data to the window because if there is to many cells your able to scroll which gives a break in the overlay on the window.  Where as using the .window property does what i need it to do.  I simply just need the `gesture` to recognize with when my cell opens the fields i dynamically populate.

Comment: Don't add tons of stuff to your window. Unless you are doing something really fancy, you should hardly mess with the window at all. Instead create a shared super view. And then you can obviously apply gesture recognisers at that level.

Comment: @timbodeit couldn't I simply do a `view.window`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69018/discussion-between-tim-bodeit-and-david-biga).

Answer (score 0):

ADD TAP GESTURE ON VIEW

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapBehind:)];
    recognizer.delegate  = self; 
    [recognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //So the user can still interact with controls in the modal view
    [self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

handleTapBehind Method :

```
- (void)handleTapBehind:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
          [self.view.window removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
          // Dismiss Your Keyboard HERE    
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to remove the gesture recognizer, what happens if the keyboard appears again

Comment: At beginEdit of Textfield Add again TAP.

Comment: @kiritmodi this is exactly what I am doing and does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a cheap workaround but if you have a better idea please let me know.

Because I have cells that are populated in a `uitableview` I am listening for a specific cell that is clicked.  So what I did is just create a `gesture` container and add that to the `view.window` on that specific cell that I listened for and that did the charm.

`[self.view.window addGestureRecognizer:self.gestureRecognizer];`